# Error while calling CouchDB from curl with multiple keys

Tags: couchdb

When I try to do a Couchdb query with curl, I get this error:

> curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 100

My query looks like this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/db/_design/records/_view/query?key=\[\"abc.com\",\"215.211.211.211\"\]
```

My view function is:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.domain, doc.ip])
}
```

What could be the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url encode your query params, so `%22` for `"` etc.

Comment: You mean like this: curl -X GET http: //localhost:5984/db/_design/records/_view/query?key=[%22abc.com%22,%22215.211.211.211%22]   ...?

Comment: Basically every non alphanumeric needs to be encoded, [here's a google result I got for "url encoding"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Why, oh why @smathy? That really hurt. Linking to w3schools is just ... oy!

Comment: I've never understood the w3schools hate - I think they do a decent job in their market.  But really I just picked the first google result.